# Push R matrix to D3 to create an animated ellipse chart

Tags: r, d3.js

I have an R function that calculates points that make up an ellipse for 3 different time based data series and returns a matrix object (essentially a row/col table of values represented the xy points).

Within R I can use these points to create an ellipse chart.

What I'm looking to do is somehow send these values to D3.js where I can then animate the the time series - 1 ellipse to the other etc..

This is much better than plotting 3 ellipses on the one chart.

One way I can do it I suppose is export a CSV from R and then pick that up in D3.  Do you think this is the best way to do it?

Comment: D3 can work with many data formats, including JSON, CSV, TSV... It really doesn't matter where the data comes from as long as it's in a format that you can work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you have a choice, CSV is probably the best format to use for d3.  CSV is more space efficient than JSON, which can improve loading times [1].

As you are likely aware, you can export the matrix from R to CSV using `write`:

```
write.matrix(format(moDat2, scientific=FALSE), 
           file = paste(targetPath, "example.csv", sep="/"), sep=",")
```

You can then check you data in d3 using:

```
d3.csv("example.csv", function (error, data) {
    console.log(data) // you can see an example on how to process data here in [2]
});
```

If you have a particular question about how to render the chart in d3, please ask that in another question, with details on what you are trying to do.  But it sounds like you already know what to do.

1. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV
2. http://tonygarcia.me/slides/d3chartintro/#chart-data

Comment: Thanks Eric.  I had this in mind.  I wonder if one day we'll be able to call R functions from within JS.  Also thanks for sharing links.